# Obscure compiler's lambda expression translation

Tags: c#, performance, compiler-construction, lambda

I studyed Y Combinator (using c# 5.0) and was quite surprised when this method:

```
public static  Func<T1, Func<T2, TOut>> Curry<T1, T2, TOut> ( this Func<T1, T2, TOut> f)
{
    return a => b => f(a, b);
}
```

... was translated by the compiler to this:

```
public static Func<T1, Func<T2, TOut>> Curry<T1, T2, TOut>(this Func<T1, T2, TOut> f)
        {
            first<T1, T2, TOut> local = new first<T1, T2, TOut>();
            local.function = f;
            return new Func<T1, Func<T2, TOut>>(local.Curry);
        }
    private sealed class first<T1, T2, TOut>
    {
        private sealed class second
        {
            public first<T1, T2, TOut> ancestor;
            public T1 firstParameter;
            public TOut Curry(T2 secondParameter)
            {
                return ancestor.function(firstParameter, secondParameter);
            }
        }
        public Func<T1, T2, TOut> function;
        public Func<T2, TOut> Curry(T1 firstParameter)
        {
            second local = new second();
            local.ancestor = this;
            local.firstParameter = firstParameter;
            return new Func<T2, TOut>(local.Curry);
        }
    }
```

So, second class is nested and first class isn't available for garbage collection while we use delegate that references to second.Curry. At the same time all that we need in first class is **function**. May be we can copy it (delegate) to the second class and then the first class could be collected? Yes, we also should then do second class non-nested but it seems that is ok. As I know delegates are copyed "by value" so I can suggest that it is quite slow, but at the same time we copy **firstParameter**?! So, may be anyone could explain, why the compiler do all this things?)
I speak about anything like this:

```
private sealed class first<T1, T2, TOut>
{
        public Func<T1, T2, TOut> function;
        public Func<T2, TOut> Curry(T1 firstParameter)
        {
            second<T1, T2, TOut> local = new second<T1, T2, TOut>();
            local.function = function;
            local.firstParameter = firstParameter;
            return new Func<T2, TOut>(local.Curry);
        }
    }
    public sealed class second<T1, T2, TOut>
    {
        public T1 firstParameter;
        public Func<T1, T2, TOut> function;
        public TOut Curry(T2 secondParameter)
        {
            return function(firstParameter, secondParameter);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Side question - can you give some link or show practical usage of your Curry method?

Comment: You need more than the function, you're closing over parameter `a` so you need to store that.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: Currying allows you to turn a function of two parameters into a function of one parameter that returns a function of one parameter. Suppose for example you have a function `add` that is `(a,b)=>a+b`.  By currying that you have a function `makeAdder` that takes a number and returns you a function that adds that number to a number.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy looks like standard implementation of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying Code likely will look like `var add5 = Add.Curry(5)`.

Comment: Alexei, second class has ancestor field, and so our first class can't be collected until second exist and second exist because our delegate has reference on second.Curry

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: The point of Currying is not so much that it is practical, but rather that it shows that if you can analyze functions of one parameter, you can analyze functions of *any* number of parameters. If you have a function of n parameters that you want to analyze, curry it into n functions of one parameter each and then analyze each.

Comment: @EvgeniyKluchikov I'm not sure I follow - are you saying delegates *never* get GC's and serve as roots?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I think the OP is pointing out that `second` only uses `ancestor` to get at `function`, so why not have `second` hold on to `function` rather than holding on to `ancestor`? His idea is then that `ancestor` could be collected earlier.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy - note that you likely use currying a lot just in less functional way. I.e. something like [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) can by considered as curried version of `jQuery.ajax` call.

Comment: @EricLippert thanks for nice explanation, very interesting - will take a closer look on currying

Comment: @EricLippert - makes sense with your explanation - I just read that statement in more assertive way.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: No, I don't so that delegates never get GC's, but if we curry our function first and then use our delegate for quite a long time, so our second class will alive all this time.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yep, reading that article, still need some time to understand it. That's why I'm not in C# compiler team :)

Comment: @EvgeniyKluchikov - got it - lack of "... earlier" in that sentence made me think you are talking about it never being GCed.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Yes, you are write. Sorry, my English is not well, I fix it.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: This article is also good: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/01/29/currying-and-partial-function-application.aspx and I talk a bit about it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/25/mmm-curry.aspx

Comment: @EricLippert thanks again for links. Interesting point about currying and extension methods in your article!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is difficult to understand. Let me clarify it. Your suggestion is that the compiler could instead generate

```
public static Func<T1, Func<T2, TOut>> Curry<T1, T2, TOut>(this Func<T1, T2, TOut> f)
{
    first<T1, T2, TOut> local = new first<T1, T2, TOut>();
    local.function = f;
    return new Func<T1, Func<T2, TOut>>(local.Curry);
}
private sealed class first<T1, T2, TOut>
{
    private sealed class second
    {
        //public first<T1, T2, TOut> ancestor;
        public Func<T1, T2, TOut> function;
        public T1 firstParameter;
        public TOut Curry(T2 secondParameter)
        {
            return /*ancestor.*/function(firstParameter, secondParameter);
        }
    }
    // public Func<T1, T2, TOut> function;
    public Func<T2, TOut> Curry(T1 firstParameter)
    {
        second local = new second();
        // local.ancestor = this;
        local.function = function;
        local.firstParameter = firstParameter;
        return new Func<T2, TOut>(local.Curry);
    }
}
```

Yes?

Your claim is that this is an improvement because of this scenario.

```
Func<int, int, int> adder = (x, y)=>x+y;
Func<int, Func<int, int>> makeAdder = adder.Curry();
Func<int, int> addFive = makeAdder(5);
```

- `addFive` is a delegate of a method on an instance of `second`
- `makeAdder` is a delegate of a method on an instance of `first`
- In the original codegen, `second` holds on to `ancestor`, which is that same instance of `first`

Therefore if we say

```
makeAdder = null;
```

then the instance of `first` cannot be collected. The instance is not reachable via `makeAdder` anymore, but it is reachable via `addFive`.

In the proposed codegen, `first` can be collected in this scenario because the instance is not reachable via `addFive`.

You are correct that *in this particular scenario* that optimization would be legal. However it would not *in general* be legal for the reason that Ben Voigt describes in his answer. **If `f` is mutated inside `Curry` then `local.function` has to mutate.** But `local` has no access to an instance of `second` **until the outer delegate is executed**.

The C# compiler team could choose to do the optimization you've identified, but the tiny savings has thus far simply not worth the bother.

We were considering for Roslyn making an optimization along the lines that you describe; that is, if the outer variable is *known not to mutate* then capture its value more aggressively. I do not know whether that optimization made it in to Roslyn or not.

Comment: Improved locality of reference is probably more important than memory footprint.  And still negligible in any non-toy program.

Comment: I wonder if there's any code out there that uses reflection to reach inside compiler-generated closure types.  Obviously such would be ill-advised.  But would serialization frameworks do such a thing automatically?

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Thank you a lot. It became much clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You've used the lambda operator twice, so you will get two anonymous delegates, with captured variables lifted into state types.

The reason that the inner lambda's state type holds the outer lambda's state type by reference is that this is how capturing works in C#: You capture a *variable*, not its value.

Some other languages (e.g. C++11 lambdas) have alternate syntax to indicate capture by-value vs capture by-reference.  C# does not, and simply captures everything by reference.  There's not really a good reason to support by-value semantics, because garbage collection avoids the lifetime problems that would exist in C++11 without a capture by-value mode.

---

Could the C# compiler notice that the variable is never written to, and therefore capturing by value is indistinguishable from capturing by reference?  Probably, but that's extra logic in the compiler, extra reviews for both the design and the code, extra tests.  All for a small, almost trivial  improvement in memory footprint and locality.  It evidently doesn't meet the cost-benefit bar, which you can find discussed in quite a few of Eric Lippert's blog articles.

Comment: Also, the JIT compiler might simplify this further when executed.

Comment: @Grzenio: I don't think merging types is one of the optimizations the JIT is allowed to do.  However difficult this is for the C# compiler to do with a high-level view of the code, it's far worse for the JIT.  Remember that neither has a whole-program view.  This is the opposite of cross-module inlining, because it requires knowing not just assemblies used by the object, but all users.  What prevents another piece of code from using reflection to change `ancestor.function`?

Comment: The C# compiler can feel free to break programs which use reflection in such a way, because that's meddling in C# implementation details.  But the JIT cannot, as it doesn't own these details, the C# compiler does.

Comment: We were considering the optimization you allude to -- noticing that an outer variable is never mutated after the delegate is created and capturing it by value -- for Roslyn but I do not know if it ever got implemented.

Comment: Yes, I don't think that this can be actual only in this special situation, thank you a lot for clear explanation.